# Different Recommendations...Using Mahout

Tags: mahout

I have written an application such that when i give it an Id for recommendation it results in successful recommendations. However, when I make a follow-up request it gives me the same recommendations. I would like it to return different recommendations.

Thanks

Comment: It's really not clear what you are trying to do. Unless the data has changed, why would the result change?

Answer (score 2):

If the result list is large enough, you could consider shuffling the list and returning a subset of it.