# Different Recommendation for each time using mahout

Tags: java, mahout

Can anybody help me ?

If i already  recommend some items to some user and suppose that user is not interested in those recommended items  and he want to see more recommendations which are different from old one's.

Is there any mechanism or concept available in mahout which helps me to get new recommendation's other than old ones which were already recommended to user ......

Answer (score 3):

Yes. One way is to interpret this as like ratings. "Not interested" means a low rating of some kind. This is easy, and mostly works. However I don't like the approach. It depends on your application, but usually "not interested" means "irrelevant". It's best not to treat that as a rating.

The better way is to supply a `Rescorer` object to `recommend()` which filters out all item IDs that the user has marked as "not interested".

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do (which is suggested in [this answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5892411/150992) is to randomly pick a subset of recommendations that are "good enough", and present them. That way each time the recommender is used, different answers will be returned. It's not perfect - if there aren't many recommendations, they will always be returned (depending on the size of your subset) but it's a simple solution, more simple than using a Rescorer and marking user disinterest.